# Adjusting vertical spacing in fractions?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  t = \frac{\dfrac{T_1}{T_2}}{1+\dfrac{Q_1}{Q_2}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

It produces:
[image]

For my taste, the vertical spacing above and below the fraction line is too small. I'm aware of the various questions that have been asked before (e.g., ["vertical spacing in nested fraction"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279004/vertical-spacing-in-nested-fraction)), but I do not find the solutions advocated there to be satisfactory.

What I would like to be able to do is to set either a global factor (for all fractions) or a local factor (for a specific fraction) that stretches the default spacing.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

**Edits:**

1. In the above MWE, the fraction is much simpler than the one I'm grappling with in my real document. So replacing the `\frac`'s by `/` won't help.
2. As suggested by my question, what I would like to have is a command that allows me to influence the spacing *without* changing the typesetting of the equation itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After unsuccessfully playing around trying to find a fix, I searched `tex.stackexchange.com` once more and found [too little space between the bar on the denominator and the horizontal line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34237/too-little-space-between-the-bar-on-the-denominator-and-the-horizontal-line), where [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) [proposed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34237/too-little-space-between-the-bar-on-the-denominator-and-the-horizontal-line/34243#34243) building on `amsmath`'s `\genfrac` command thus:

```
\newcommand{\myfrac}[3][0pt]{\genfrac{}{}{}{}{\raisebox{#1}{$#2$}}{\raisebox{-#1}{$#3$}}}
```

This does nearly all of what I want. The updated MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\myfrac}[3][0pt]{\genfrac{}{}{}{}{\raisebox{#1}{$#2$}}{\raisebox{-#1}{$#3$}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  t = \frac{\dfrac{T_1}{T_2}}{1+\dfrac{Q_1}{Q_2}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  t = \myfrac[7pt]{\dfrac{T_1}{T_2}}{1+\dfrac{Q_1}{Q_2}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

and gives

[image]

Separating the amounts by which the boxes are raised and lowered is a trivial extension:

```
\usepackage{twoopt}
\newcommandtwoopt{\myfrac}[4][0pt][0pt]{\genfrac{}{}{}{}{\raisebox{#1}{$#3$}}{\raisebox{-#2}{$#4$}}}
```

Comment: Accepting my own answer feels odd, but it comes closest to doing what I originally looked for...

Answer (score 8):

You can use `\cfrac`, which is thought for continued fractions, which this is a case of:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
t =
\frac{\dfrac{T_1}{T_2}}{1+\dfrac{Q_1}{Q_2}}=
\cfrac{\cfrac{T_1}{T_2}}{1+\cfrac{Q_1}{Q_2}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fair enough, but it only seems to influence the spacing between the fraction line and the bottom fraction. I would like to also be able to influence the spacing between the fraction line and the top fraction.

Comment: @user1362373 not only, $T_1$ is also higher!

Answer (score 5):

I would use inline-fraction notation rather than stack two `\dfrac` expressions. The presence of the `/` characters ensures almost automatically that the numerator and denominator terms are not placed too closely to the fraction bar.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\dfrac" macro and "equation*" env.
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
   t=\dfrac{T_1/T_2}{1+Q_1/Q_2}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not an option because in my real example the fractions are a lot more complicated and typesetting them in this way would make them hard to read.

Answer (score 4):

Use\cfrac, combined with `\bigstrut` for the numerator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 t = \frac{\cfrac{T_1}{T_2\bigstrut[b]}}{1+\cfrac{Q_1}{Q_2}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this goes in the direction I want. How could I turn this into something that does not require me to insert extra commands into the fraction itself?

Comment: Probably, you would have to delve into the low level coding of `\cfrac` to see how to patch it. Not sure it's worth this effort, unless you really have  many fractions that require it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late, but I have been experiencing the same problem.
Until now I have been passive about it, but after I made the effort to switch to MathTime Pro II, I decided it was time to try to find a solution. After reading these posts:

[Adjusting vertical spacing in fractions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500157/adjusting-vertical-spacing-in-fractions)

[Increase the vertical space in a fraction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522544/increase-the-vertical-space-in-a-fraction/522551#522551)

[\frac with mathpazo: bar too close to denominator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612603/frac-with-mathpazo-bar-too-close-to-denominator/612633#612633)

[Add whitespace around a box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39567/add-whitespace-around-a-box)

[too little space between the bar on the denominator and the horizontal line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34237/too-little-space-between-the-bar-on-the-denominator-and-the-horizontal-line)

I came to the conclusion that the amsmath command \genfrac would probably meet my requirements **if** I could find a way to redefine/fine-tune the division line.
According to the **User’s Guide for the amsmath Package (Version 2.0)**, the signature of \genfrac is as follows:

```
\genfrac{left-delim}{right-delim}{thickness}{mathstyle}{numerator}{denominator}
```

Hence, if one could patch the existing definition with a new API that splits the thickness parameter into three sub-arguments, namely:

- totalthickness (e.g. 1pt)
- visiblethickness (e.g. 0.6pt)
- position ("b", "t" or "c")

it would give me enough degrees of freedom without (I believe) endangering the typography of either TeX or mtpro2.

> In words: I would like to be able to define a visible part of \genfrac's division line, that can be centered ("c") or moved up ("t") and down ("b") within the total height (thickness) of the line.
> Today, visiblethickness = totalthickness => only one degree of freedom.

Regarding the details, I am vague since I have no experience with programming in TeX at this level, so I leave the idea here for a while to see if someone who is more skilled than me picks it up before I make an attempt myself.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the vertical spacing above and below the fraction line, we can use TikZ to customize as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\begin{document}
This is from OP. The vertical spacing above and below the fraction line is too small.
\begin{equation*}
t = \frac{\dfrac{T_1}{T_2}}{1+\dfrac{Q_1}{Q_2}}
\end{equation*}

To increase the vertical spacing above and below the fraction line, we can use TikZ to customize as follows.

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\d{1} % length of fraction line
\draw 
(0,0)     node[left]{$t=$}--+(0:\d)++(0:\d/2)
+(90:.5)  node{$\dfrac{T_1}{T_2}$}
+(-90:.5) node{$1+\dfrac{Q_1}{Q_2}$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems quite a complicated solution compared to what I'm looking for.