# Increase the vertical space in a fraction

Tags: spacing, fractions, white-space, vertical-spacing

I intend to create a vertical space between the number 39 and the horizontal bar of the fraction, so as not to get crowded. How can I create the vertical space?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=10mm,rmargin=10mm,bmargin=30mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
A=\left.\dfrac{\dfrac{80}{39}}{\cancel{s}\Bigg(s+\dfrac{17}{39}\Bigg)}\cancel{s}\,\right\vert_{s=0}
=\left.\frac{\dfrac{80}{39}}{s+\dfrac{17}{39}}\right\vert_{s=0}=\frac{\dfrac{80}{39}}{\dfrac{17}{39}}=\dfrac{80}{\cancel{39}}\times \dfrac{\cancel{39}}{17}=\dfrac{80}{17}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose one oft these solutions:  either add a `\bigstrut[b]` to the fractions in the numerator, a `\bigstrut[t]` to the fractions in the denominator at the relevant places, or the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath`. I added various improvements to your code, like  using `\cfrac` in the place of `\dfrac` for the nested fractions, and the paits  `\biggl ... \biggr`, and the like, for a better vertical spacing of the delimiters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=10mm, bmargin=30mm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
A=\left.\frac{\cfrac{80}{39\bigstrut[b]}}{\cancel{s}\biggl(s+\cfrac{17}{39}\biggr)}\cancel{s}\,\right\rvert_{s=0}
=\left.\frac{\cfrac{80}{39\bigstrut[b]}}{s+\cfrac{17\bigstrut[t]}{39}}\right\vert_{s=0}=\frac{\cfrac{80}{39\bigstrut[b]}}{\cfrac{17}{39}}=\frac{80}{\cancel{39}}\times \frac{\cancel{39}}{17}=\frac{80}{17}
\end{equation}
\bigskip

\begin{equation}
A=\left.\frac{\mfrac{80}{39}}{\cancel{s}\Bigl(s+\mfrac{17}{39}\Bigr)}\cancel{s}\,\right\rvert_{s=0}
=\left.\frac{\mfrac{80}{39}}{s+\mfrac{17}{39}}\right\vert_{s=0}=\frac{\mfrac{80}{39}}{\mfrac{17}{39}}=\frac{80}{\cancel{39}}\times \frac{\cancel{39}}{17}=\frac{80}{17}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Define a couple of commands to suit your needs:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\newcommand{\ufrac}[2]{\dfrac{#1}{#2\mathstrut}} % upper fraction
\newcommand{\lfrac}[2]{\dfrac{#1\mathstrut}{#2}} % lower fraction

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
A=\left.\frac{\ufrac{80}{39}}{\cancel{s}\biggl(s+\lfrac{17}{39}\biggr)}\cancel{s}\,
  \right\vert_{s=0}
 =\left.\frac{\ufrac{80}{39}}{s+\lfrac{17}{39}}\right\vert_{s=0}
 =\frac{\ufrac{80}{39}}{\lfrac{17}{39}}
 =\dfrac{80}{\cancel{39}}\times \dfrac{\cancel{39}}{17}=\dfrac{80}{17}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility. I use `\dpstrut{1ex}` in this example and `1ex` is too much—this is just to make the effect clearly visible. My `\dpstrut` command only adds an invisible rule with zero height and width, plus configurable depth where it is used; it doesn't change anything else.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\newcommand*{\dpstrut}[1]{\vrule width 0pt height 0pt depth #1\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
A=\left.\dfrac{\dfrac{80}{\dpstrut{1ex}39}}{\cancel{s}\Bigg(s+\dfrac{17}{39}\Bigg)}\cancel{s}\,\right\vert_{s=0}
=\left.\frac{\dfrac{80}{39}}{s+\dfrac{17}{39}}\right\vert_{s=0}=\frac{\dfrac{80}{39}}{\dfrac{17}{39}}=\dfrac{80}{\cancel{39}}\times \dfrac{\cancel{39}}{17}=\dfrac{80}{17}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unrelated: I believe you would be better off using `\Biggl( ... \Biggr)` instead of `\Bigg( ... \Bigg)`. This should give better spacing, because `\Biggl` and `\Biggr` give the proper `\mathopen` or `\mathclose` class to the thing being wrapped, contrary to just `\Bigg` which is a `\mathord` (due to the use of `\hbox`) as seen from outside.